# Restart a Supervisor managed process without root

Tags: supervisord

I want some of my users to be able to restart processes that are managed by Supervisor. So I want to be able to execute a command like this as a non-root user:

```
supervisorctl restart my_process
```

Answer (score 1):

By default supervisor uses a Unix socket to communicate between `supervisorctl` and `supervisord`. This is set in the configuration file like this:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/tmp/supervisord.sock  
chmod=0770
```

Only users with access to this socket file can send messages over them. By default this socket file's owner and group are the ones from the user that runs the `supervisord` process, which is usually `root`. You can however change the user/group with the `chown` option:

```
chown=myuser:mygroup
```

You can of course also change the `chmod` option and set it to for example `0777` to give all users access to the socket, but I would discourage that.

There are even options to require a username and password for HTTP authentication over this socket. See the [supervisor documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#unix-http-server-section-settings) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`, like `/etc/sudoers.d/myuser_restart_process` containing:

```
myuser ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/supervisorctl restart process-name
```

This will allow `myuser` to execute the command `sudo /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart process-name`.

See the "Sudoers File Format" section in the `sudoers` [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) for more information on this format.